# How to set conditional mappings in VIM (ie: depending on the extension of a file)?

Tags: vim, mapping, conditional-statements

How to, for example, map `'<leader>r'` to `:!node %` **if** the file extension is **.js** and to `:!make %` otherwise?

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
nnoremap <leader>r :!make %
autocmd FileType javascript nnoremap <leader>r :!node %
```

Comment: That's interesting but what if I have my own filetype, how do I configure that to recognize it?

Comment: @Dokkat

`au BufNewFile, BufRead *.foo set filetype=foo`

Comment: Now after trying again it works like that: after I load a .js file the r is mapped, but it is then mapped everywhere...

Comment: @Dokkat Right, `au BufNewFile, BufRead *.foo set filetype=foo` should be in `filetype.vim` (in vim directory). `javascript` command works for me, what exactly do you typed in your `vimrc`?

Comment: @Dokkat I think this should help: `autocmd FileType javascript nnoremap <buffer><leader>r :!node % <cr>`

Answer (score 5):

General case, in your `~/.vimrc`:

```
nnoremap <leader>r :!make %<cr>
```

JavaScript files, in `~/after/ftplugin/javascript.vim`:

```
nnoremap <buffer> <leader>r :!node %
```

Or use the `makeprg` option. See `:h makeprg`.

Comment: +1, I would suggest to have a look to http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/usr_41.html#ftplugin too.

Comment: What is that `~/after/ftplugin`? Also what about my own filetype?

Comment: This is the place where you put your own filetype settings. If it doesn't exist create it.

Comment: The right path is `~/.vim/ftplugin`, not `~/after/ftplugin`. And `~/.vim/after/ftplugin` makes sense only if we have options that may be overwritten by the ftplugin stored `$VIM/ftplugin`. This is not the case here.
Otherwise, +1 (as well) for the ftplugin solution.

Comment: @LucHermitte, I find it safer to load my ftplugins *after* the default ones but you are right that `~/.vim/ftplugin` would be a good place in this case… until the asker tries to override some default.

Comment: In that case, he can set b:did_ftplugin. Well. A lot can be said on the subject. ^^